# In Razor Pages, what is the recommended way to run an action with no UI

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to implement a sign-out method which just signs the user out and redirects to the home page.
How would I set up the routing and would the code go into a controller, or do I need to create a new Page for this?  Would seem odd as it doesn't require a UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asp-page` specify the page name which the sign-out method is in ,  The `asp-page-handler` attribute is a companion to `asp-page`. `asp-page-handler` generates URLs that submit to each of the handler methods defined by a page. Change your `_LoginPartial.cshtml` as follows :

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
<li class="nav-item">
    <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-page="/Index" asp-page-handler="SignOut">Logout</a>
</li>
}
```

IndexModel of Home page  ,  the `RedirectToPage` parameter is combined with the path of the current page to compute the name of the destination page.

```
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LogoutModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<LogoutModel> logger)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetSignOut()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");

        return RedirectToPage("/Index");

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Reference for `RedirectToPage` :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#url-generation-for-pages

Comment: Sorry for delay - had moved onto anothe rproject. This answer is the most complete. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a method named `GetSignOut()` then add a button or an `<a></a>` tag and add this to its attributes `asp-route-handler="signout"`
Finally in your `GetSignOut()` do your signout related stuff and finally `return redirectToPage("pageName")`

Answer (score 0):

The [original Razor Pages project template included an AccountController](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/312/introduction-to-identity-in-razor-pages) that had one method - `Logout`. The justification was that the Logout process did not require a UI, so it seemed odd to create a Razor Page for it when the purpose behind Razor Pages is to generate HTML.

If you scaffold Identity into an existing project, you now get a *Logout.cshtml* file, which redirects the use to a return URL if one is provided, or displays "you have been logged out" otherwise.

So both approaches tend to suggest that the recommendation is to use Razor Pages for HTML generation, and controllers for non-HTML related services.